# How do I return stages that are performed on EVERY day of a festival?

Tags: c#

I'm a student preparing for a C# test and I have a problem. Maybe I can't phrase it properly because of my weak English, so I'll just jump to the question.

There's a festival that lasts several days and it has several stages on which bands can perform simultaneously. Not all stages are used every day of the festival.
Here's the structure:

```
public class Festival
{
    List<Performance> performances;
}

public class Performance
{
    DateTime start;
    string stage;
}
```

**I need to write a method that would return a stage (or stages) that are used EVERY day of the festival.**

I made a test program with `int day;` and `char stage;` which made it easier for me to play around with. I made it work with this code:

```
List<Performance> allPerformances = new List<Performance>();
// Above I've added my test performances (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'C') etc.

List<int> allDaysNoRepetition = new List<int>();
List<char> allStagesNoRepetition = new List<char>();

foreach (Performance p in allPerformances)
{
    if (!allDaysNoRepetition.Contains(p.day))
    {
        allDaysNoRepetition.Add(p.day);
    }
    if (!allStagesNoRepetition.Contains(p.stage))
    {
        allStagesNoRepetition.Add(p.stage);
    }
}

foreach (char stage in allStagesNoRepetition)
{
    List<int> daysOnThisStage = new List<int>();
    foreach (int day in allDaysNoRepetition)
    {
        foreach (Performance p in allPerformances)
        {
            if (p.day == day && p.stage.Equals(stage) && !daysOnThisStage.Contains(day))
            { daysOnThisStage.Add(day); }
        }
    }
    if (daysOnThisStage.Count() == allDaysNoRepetition.Count())
    { Console.WriteLine(stage); }
}
```

This works, but I wonder if there's a more elegant way to make this work other than counting distinct days on a stage and distinct days overall and then comparing? Is this the right logic with which I should approach "occurs in all" problems?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I haven't formatted this properly, I'm a rookie.

Comment: You could use `HashSet`s instead of `List`s to handle the duplicates for you.

Comment: I think the way you modeled this problem could be improved. A festival has performances *and* it has stages. Stages have performances on them at certain times. One act could even, theoretically, perform multiple times, on different stages. I would model stages as well as performances. A stage has a list containing the performances on that stage. A performance has a reference to the stage that the performance will take place on.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for replying. I agree, but unfortunately the model is given at the exam, and we're not allowed to modify it, we just write the methods they assign us.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thank you. We haven't covered them in the class, so I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

as i understood question you need to get only stages, which are busy every day of fest.
it might not be pretty, but it a different approach:

```
Festival fest = new Festival();
    List<Performance> allPerformances = new List<Performance>();
    // Above I've added my test performances (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'C') etc.
    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2019"), stage = "A"});
    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2019"), stage = "B"});
    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2019"), stage = "C"});

    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2019"), stage = "A"});
    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2019"), stage = "B"});
    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2019"), stage = "C"});

    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/3/2019"), stage = "A"});
    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/3/2019"), stage = "C"});

    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/4/2019"), stage = "A"});
    allPerformances.Add(new Performance(){day = DateTime.Parse("1/4/2019"), stage = "C"});

    fest.performances = allPerformances.OrderBy(o=>o.day).ToList();

    //get list of ALL fest days
    var listOfDays = GetDateRange( fest.performances.Min(s=>(s.day)),fest.performances.Max(s=>(s.day)));

    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    allPerformances.GroupBy(g => new { g.stage })
    .ToList().ForEach(fe => { 
        if(listOfDays.Count() == fe.Select(s=>s.day).Distinct().Count())
            result.Add(fe.Select(s=>s.stage).FirstOrDefault());
    });

    Console.Write(result);
```

and classes and function

```
public class Festival
{
    public List<Performance> performances { get; set;}
    public Festival(){performances = new List<Performance>();}
}

public class Performance
{
    public DateTime day { get; set; }
    public string stage { get; set;}
    public Performance(){}
}

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if (endDate < startDate)
        throw new ArgumentException("endDate must be greater than or equal to startDate");

    while (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        yield return startDate;
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

as result you should get A and C.
i hope i understood you correctly...

Comment: Yes, this is excatly what I needed to do.
This code is a bit advanced for me, I see functions that we haven't covered in class, but if I understand your code correctly you are also counting distinct days on each stage and days of the festival and comparing them, but in a much prettier way than I did?
Thank you for sharing your solution!

Comment: @nicecat i showed different approach to use grouping, code is clean and easy to read. :)

Comment: I see, I'm yet to get into Lambda expressions. Thank you!